# Agrupar objeto por valor

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
[
{
    "SlpName": "Vildoza Juan",
    "Patente": "SI",
    "Cantidad": 49
},
{
    "SlpName": "Bazan Andres",
    "Patente": "SI",
    "Cantidad": 28
},
{
    "SlpName": "Jaime Gustavo",
    "Patente": "SI",
    "Cantidad": 16
},
{
    "SlpName": "Vildoza Juan",
    "Patente": "NO",
    "Cantidad": 4
},
{
    "SlpName": "Bastidas Manuel",
    "Patente": "NO",
    "Cantidad": 1
}
```

]

Necesito poder agruparlos por SlpName y la cantidad de SI y NO en un solo objeto, sin repetir los nombres para poder pintarlos en un datatable. Ya que si lo mando como está la tabla me repite los nombres y me los coloca dos veces. Intenté con Reducer pero no logro conseguirlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una función que suelo utilizar array para agrupar por campo:

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function (key) {
    return this.reduce(function (rv, x) {
        var v = typeof key == 'function' ? key(x) : x[key];
        var el = rv.find(function (r) { return r && r.key === v });
        if (el)
            el.values.push(x)
        else
            rv.push({ key: v, values: [x] });
        return rv;
    }, []);
}

Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    var _len = this.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < _len; i++) {
        total += (typeof this[i] == "Object" || typeof this[i] == "object") ? this[i][prop] : this[i];
    }
    return total
}
```

se usa [].groupBy(x=> x.SlpName) y te retornaria un objeto:

```
[{key: "Vildoza Juan", values:[{"SlpName": "Vildoza Juan","Patente": "SI", "Cantidad": 49 },{"SlpName": "Vildoza Juan","Patente": "NO","Cantidad": 4}]}
,...]
```

Ya teniéndolos agrupados y con los datos en values[] podrías hacer una suma por campo y guardarlo en una lista

```
var list =[];

[].groupBy(x=> x.SlpName).forEach(x=> list.push({ SlpName:x.key, SI: x.values.filter(y=> y.Patente == "SI").sum("Cantidad")}))
```

ahí uso sum() por costumbre pero puedes usar reduce(), quedando list[] mas o menos como

```
[{SlpName: 'Vildoza Juan', SI: 49},
{SlpName: 'Bazan Andres', SI: 28},
{SlpName: 'Jaime Gustavo', SI: 16},
{SlpName: 'Bastidas Manuel', SI: 0}]
```

Eso si quieres que el formato sea de esa manera